# How can I optimize this code for performance?

Tags: python, optimization, pygame

I'm making a game in pygame, the full source code of which can be found here:

https://github.com/hailfire006/games/blob/master/strategy%20game

Unfortunately, I'm running into some frame rate issues and everything I've read about this sort of problem says it's graphical, ie it's got nothing to do with the math and everything to do with drawing the sprites.

As such, I've narrowed the problem down to the following draw function of my npc class, which is called every frame for every npc in my "objects" list.  It's got a lot of sprite rotation, a set_colorkey, and a re-sizing. All of these things are probably quite costly, so is there a way I can re-write the following code to optimize it for performance?

PS: Sorry if what I'm asking or bits of the code are unclear, point it out if something is confusing and I'll edit my question.

```
b = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
b.image = pygame.image.load("soldier.png").convert()
b.image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))

target = get_target(self)
if target != 0:
    angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(self.x - target[0], self.y - target[1])) + 90
    b.image = pygame.transform.rotate(b.image,angle)
    self.shoot(target)

if self.moving != False:
    if abs(self.x - self.moving[0]) < 1 and abs(self.y - self.moving[1]) < 1:
        self.moving = False
    else:
        self.move(self.moving)
        if target == 0:
            angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(self.x - self.moving[0],                   self.y - self.moving[1])) + 90
            b.image = pygame.transform.rotate(b.image,angle)

b.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(b.image,(50,50))
b.rect = b.image.get_rect()
b.rect.topleft = [self.x - 20, self.y - 20]
window.blit(b.image, b.rect)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Woah woah woah... are you loading and converting that .png every frame?

1. Don't do that.

Next up, instead of returning 0 from get_target, I recommend returning None. Then your next line can be:

```
if target is not None:
```

Which is *slightly* faster.

Next time, try and profile each segment of your code. You can use [python's profiling tools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/profile.html) to have a look at your code in detail, or just [write your own simple timer controller](http://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis/).

Comment: I changed the second thing, but where should I load and convert the .png, the init function?  I tried copy pasting different lines into init and got some very weird errors, could someone explain which lines need to be moved?

Comment: make "b" a variable on the npc (class?, whatever your `self` is at this point) and do the first three lines of this class inside your class __init__

Comment: also name your variable something other than "b"!!! (.sprite is a MUCH better alternative)

Comment: I did that and now it works until I try to move the npc.  he flies off the map towards the bottom right and continues infinitely until it throws this error:
       

     line 53, in draw self.sprite.image =     pygame.transform.rotate(self.sprite.image,angle)
error: Out of memory

Comment: Add that as a new question with more detailed information and accept the answer here if I've solved your performance issue :)

Comment: I'd love to, but without moving my npcs i can't test whether it did solve the performance issue :(

Comment: Also, initial guess is you don't need the first part of that line of code, simply calling pygame.transform.rotate(self.sprite.image, angle) should be sufficient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89866/discussion-between-vikram-saran-and-user3150635).